# How to manipulate data by Symfony Form (with JS, AJAX)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, symfony-forms, data-manipulation

I've got a short question. Let's say I have the data from database in my Symfony app and on the same page I have a form which is responsible for manipulate these data. Saying "manipulate" I mean: displaying or hiding some data and sorting them. I think the best way to achieve this would be use a JavaScript/AJAX. The thing is I never wrote even JavaScript **in my Symfony apps** and I completly don't know how to go about it.

Have you got some link to documentation, tutorial or article which will show me how to manipulate data by JavaScript/AJAX in Symfony? Or could you please explain me it in a few words?

Thank you in advance for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Symfony, we use and compile JS files as assets in order to use them on pages. You might want to use JQuery when performing AJAX-requests. Using JQuery, AJAX can be coded by the following way:

```
$.ajax({
   url: <insert url here>,
   type: <insert type here, for example, GET>,
   dataType: <insert data type here, for example, json>,
   success:function(data) {
      <Implement a function which is applied after a successful request. Variable "data" is the result of the request.>
   }
   error:function(data) {
      <Optionally, implement a function which shows information when request was not successful.>
   }
});
```

For example, you have the class `.cl` on page and want to change HTML code of it. Then use `$('.cl').replaceWith($(data).find('.cl'))` in the success function.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I'm sorry but I couldn't reply earlier. 
Alright, let's assume I've added the function you wrote above to assets. But is something else needed inside controller or Doctrine repository except the function? In other words, is the function self-sufficient to manipulate the data?

Comment: You need to include <script src="{{ assets('path/to/file') }}"></script> in your .twig template. Also, make sure that JQuery is included in your JS file.